# Surefire plugin crashed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, maven-surefire-plugin, serenity-bdd

While running serenity automation, encountered this issue

/bin/sh: line 1: 17472 Killed
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (default) on project freshmarketer-automation-serenity: There are test failures.

Didnt face this so far and no changes has been done to jenkins CI

Automation job is triggered in jenkins and received this exception before the test case execution starts

Dependencies added in pom.xml

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```